# "Error: Actions must be plain objects" on Array of actions returned from epics

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

On all set of actions returned from epics we get this error.

it could be due to how epics are set up in the `epics` creator:

```
const epic = (action$, store) => 
   action$.ofType(String(key)).mergeMap(action => func(action, store))
```

either the mappings are not correct here or more probably they are not correct in the epics.

Example of one epic called by `func(action, store)`:

```
  [String(usersActions.updateUser)]: (action, store) => {
    return authFetch(`${API_ROOT}/user/${get(action, 'payload.id')}`, {
      method: 'put',
      headers: {
       ...
      },
      body: ...,
    })
      .then(resJson => {
        if (resJson['status'] === 200) {
          return [
            appActions.pushNotification('success', USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS),
            appActions.setNextPath(`/users/${get(action, 'payload.id')}`),
          ]
        } else
          return [
            appActions.pushNotification(
              'error',
              USER_UPDATE_FAILED + ': ' + resJson['message']
            ),
          ]
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return [appActions.pushNotification('error', USER_UPDATE_FAILED)]
      })
  },
```

It works correctly if the square parenthesis are not there, tried with this suggestion too:

```
  [String(usersActions.updateUser)]: (action, store) => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
      fetch(`${API_ROOT}/user/${get(action, 'payload.id')}`, {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {},
      }).then(res => res.json())
    )
      .mergeMap(resJson => {
        if (resJson['status'] === 200) {
          return Rx.Observable.concat(
            Rx.Observable.of(
              appActions.pushNotification('success', USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS)
            ),
            Rx.Observable.of(
              appActions.setNextPath(`/users/${get(action, 'payload.id')}`)
            )
          )
        } else return
        Rx.Observable.concat(
          Rx.Observable.of(
            appActions.pushNotification(
              'error',
              USER_UPDATE_FAILED + ': ' + resJson['message']
            )
          )
        )
      })
      .catch(() => {
        Rx.Observable.concat(
          Rx.Observable.of(
            appActions.pushNotification('error', USER_UPDATE_FAILED)
          )
        )
      })
  },
```

it removes the error but the actions dispatched are now duplicated.

Already tried will all the options out there so hopefully it's not a repeated question.

Comment: Can you simplify to a minimal reproducible example? I'm not able to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.do(action => console.log(action))` to the end of your epic to see what value(s) you're emitting and why they are not actions. e.g. if it's an array of actions, that's incorrect. Epics should only ever emit plain old javascript actions with a `type` property.

Comment: Hi @jayphelps , thanks for the help. In the end the first epic style was correct. I had to add  `.flatMap(e => (e instanceof Array ? e : [e]))` to the `epics` creator and pass the actions with `raw` otherwise they are dispatched more than once.